# SQL index column always value from 1 to N

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think my question is very simple but every search in the web shows me results about SQL indexing.

I use the following SQL query to create a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE SpeechOutputList
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    SpeechConfigCode nvarchar(36) NOT NULL,
    OutputSentence nvarchar(500),
    IsPrimaryOutput bit DEFAULT 0,

    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(SpeechConfigCode) 
        REFERENCES SpeechConfig 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I would like to add an index column that increases automatically (not `identity(1,1)`) which always has values from 1 to N (according to the number of rows).

`identity(1,1)` will not do since there are many cases there are no continues numbers from 1 to N because it's intended for primary key.

Thanks

Comment: what happen if you delete a record in between ? You will need to re-sequence your index column ?

Comment: Yes that's right, is there any build in function for doing so? @Squirrel

Comment: nope. You have to do it in trigger

Comment: what is the use of this `index` column ? You can generate the sequence no using `row_number()` in a `select` query

Comment: The porpuse is to enable the user to insert a new record at a specific index @Squirrel

Comment: You're best doing that programatically then.  Have your application manage the values.  When you insert a row at `ix = X` first run `UPDATE SpeechOutputList SET ix = ix + 1` and *then* run your INSERT statement, explicitly providing the value of x being inserted.  Similarly, when you delete a row, subsequently run an update statement.  Also include an actual index on that field.  *(Note, I wouldn't call this field `index`, that's a key word in SQL.)*

Comment: Alternatively, use a `FLOAT` data-type.  If you have values `1, 2, 3, 4` and want to insert before `4`, use `3.5`.  This is more useful for very large tables where you don't want to do the large updates *(which will rapidly become expensive)*, but is instead more complex to manage; if you want to insert before `4`, you need to also find the largest value before the `4` then your new value to insert becomes `(4 + (next lowest value)) / 2` which in the example above is `(4+3)/2 = 3.5`.

Comment: I think I'll go on your first option as this table contains relatively small amount of records. Thank you @MatBailie

Comment: I made a typo, I forgot a where clause...  `UPDATE SpeechOutputList SET ix = ix + 1 WHERE ix >= @x`

Comment: Is the order important, or can these 1..N numbers be assigned arbitrarily?

Comment: Can be assign arbitrarily but in some cases I have to allow the user to insert a row with specific index. @trincot

Comment: If it is a specific index, then what if that index is already taken? Refuse the insert with a duplicate error? NB: renumbering many records reduces concurrence, as the whole table will be locked during the operation. But one has to wonder: what is the use of this index. Can you explain? What if a record is deleted and a gap in your sequence appears?

Comment: I thought there is a build-in sql function that to all of these operations and take care about all the edge cases you mentioned above. Just like the identity(1,1) except that identity doesn't take care about gaps (as it should be). As other nice programmers written above, there is no any such build-in function and I, probably, should take care of it by my self (maybe even programmatically). Thanks @trincot

Comment: If you would explain the purpose of the index, we could make better suggestions. As someone said above, you could add the number in real-time when selecting from the table. That might be more efficient than trying to store and correct whenever a change is made.

Comment: I would like to enable the user to add sentences (records into the above table). But, he could decide which is the main sentence. At first I thought about a flag to mark one of them as primary (1) and the other as 0. That caused me to iterate all over the records and mark them accordingly on every user-update. So I decided to take the first sentence as a primary sentence. But what if the user wants to change that? How can I move the desired sentence to the top so it will be the primary sentence? This is the requirements in generally speaking. Thank you again @trincot

Comment: But for that purpose gaps would be OK, no?

Comment: Actually yes it will be OK, is there any way to do so without updating the other? @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to keep such an index field sequential, and without gaps, will not be efficient. If for instance a record is removed, you would need to have a trigger that renumbers the records that follow. This will take not only extra time, it will also reduce concurrency.

Furthermore, that index will not be a stable key for a record. If a client would get the index value of a record, and then later would try to locate it again by that index, it might well get a different record as a result.

If you still believe such an index is useful, I would suggest to create a view that will add this index on-the-fly:

```
CREATE VIEW SpeechOutputListEx AS
SELECT ID, SpeechConfigCode, OutputSentence, IsPrimaryOutput,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS idx
FROM   SpeechOutputList
```

This will make it possible to do selections, like:

```
SELECT * FROM SpeechOutputListEx WHERE idx = 5
```

To make an update, with a condition on the index, you would take the join with the view:

```
UPDATE s
SET        OutputSentence = 'sentence'
FROM       SpeechOutputList s
INNER JOIN SpeechOutputListEx se
        ON s.ID = se.ID
WHERE      idx = 5
```

#### The issue of primary:

You explained in comments that the order should indicate whether a sentence is primary.

For that purpose you don't need the view. You could add a column `idx`, that would allow gaps. Then just let the user determine the value of the `idx` column. Even if negative, that would not be an issue. You would select in order of `idx` value and so get the primary sentence first.

If a sentence would have to be made *primary*, you could issue this update:

```
update SpeechOutputList
set    idx = (select min(idx) - 1 from SpeechOutputList)
where  id = 123
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution doing so except that I have to take into account the case where the idx number is on it's limit (as this table is subject to have many changes by many users). In such case I should iterate all over the records and reset/update their idx value. Thank you!

Comment: If you define that field as an `int`, you can have values going down to -2^31, which means you can change which is the primary sentence 1 billion times before getting into problems. That means if you have such an update every second 24/24, you still wont hit the limit in the next 30 years. If you still doubt, go for `bigint`, and then its not reasonable to think you ever hit the limit.